# Indexing to Elasticsearch locally with biosentvec TimeoutError

Tags: python, elasticsearch, timeouterror

I am trying to index 300k observations locally with elastic search, been trying to crawl the biosentvec api after creating embeddings to index the entire data it keeps breaking. i get the following error.

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond', None, 10060, None))

The entire error is below

```
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 449, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 444, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\bsv_Env\lib\http\client.py", line 1348, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\bsv_Env\lib\http\client.py", line 316, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\bsv_Env\lib\http\client.py", line 277, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\bsv_Env\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\bsv_Env\lib\ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\bsv_Env\lib\ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 550, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 769, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 449, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 444, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\bsv_Env\lib\http\client.py", line 1348, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\bsv_Env\lib\http\client.py", line 316, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\bsv_Env\lib\http\client.py", line 277, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\bsv_Env\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\bsv_Env\lib\ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\bsv_Env\lib\ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond', None, 10060, None))
```

The configuration i used for my client and defined function for the biosentvec api where i believe the error is are below.

```
client = Elasticsearch(hosts=const.HOSTS, timeout=30, max_retries=10, retry_on_timeout=True)

def run_bio_sent_vec_api(input):
    result = {} 
    script_query = {
      "query": input
    }
    headers = {"Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json",
               'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    url = "https://biosentvec-proxy-r7tozhc6ua-uc.a.run.app/fetchEmbedding"
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=script_query)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        result = response.json()['biosentvec']
    else:
        print('Error:', response.status_code)
    return result
```

Comment: why are you init a `client` if you're not using it?

Comment: assuming you're trying to index 300k docs, I would suggest to use the `bulk` helper to avoid timeouts... https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.5.2/helpers.html#example

Comment: @ItayB I am using it, for some reason i think the problem lies only in the user defined function. i could put up the entire code for your perusal.

Comment: yes please. It doesn't look like you're using it if you're using `requsts.post` for sending the query